# php using two equal operator

Tags: php, for-loop, operators, equals

my original code is:

```
$name = '';

for($i = 0;$i < 10; $i++) {
    $name .= '1';
}
```

i edited to following code

```
for($name = $i = '';$i < 10; $i++) {
    $name .= '1';
}

echo $name;
```

output is `1111111111`

var_dump: `string(10) "1111111111"`

is this valid code?

can i use multiple equal operator like `$name = $i = ''`?

and why i set it to `''` empty string

but `for{}` function can successfully looping `1`?

`$i` isn't must be integer to `$i++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works is because `+` automatically converts its arguments to numbers, and any string that doesn't begin with a number converts to 0.

But this code is really confusing, and I wouldn't recommend it. If you want to initialize `$name` in the loop, you can write:

```
for ($name = '', $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $name .= '1';
}
```

But I don't see why you think this is necessary. Your original code is the way most PHP programmers would write it. There's no gain from putting the string initialization in the `for` header.

Conversely, if you want to get really compact, you can write:

```
for ($name = $i = ''; $name .= '1', ++$i < 10; );
```

I'm not endorsing that last code, it's just a demonstration of the power of the comma operator and pre-increment.

Comment: awesome statement for this question "But this code is really confusing, and I wouldn't recommend it" ;p

Comment: @hek2mgl No, the comma is necessary there. Otherwise `++$i < 10` will be moved into the increment field instead of the end-test field.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I see, nice :) I had expected this: `for ($name = $i = ''; ++$i < 10; $name .= '1');` .. It's two chars less :) but yours is nice anyway

Comment: @Barmar :O Don't let my cat hear that :) .. (et)jk_jk.. Barmer told that his code was just a *bad* example. If you are searching for a one liner to solve this problem use: `$name = str_repeat('1', 10);` It's faster and much more readable.

Comment: @hek2mgl '1' just in this example, my function uses array_rand(), so need the string different everytime generated, `for` works for me but `str_repeat` just return something like `ssssssss`,`for` return `iergvfuh`

Comment: ah ok. what about good old `uniqid()`? does it suite for you?

Answer (score 1):

> can i use multiple equal operator like $name = $i = ''

Yes this is possible as you see

> and why i set it to '' empty string

The loose typing system of php will convert an empty string in an integer operation into `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you try this,

```
$i = '';
$i++;
echo $i;
```

you can see that the output = 1.

Since you need to compare `$i with 10` in your code, **php dynamically converts i** to integer and assigns 0.

Remember that `php` is ***`dynamically typed language`***.